# I set the toValue of rotation to 2*PI, but why after the animation these views are not horizontal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

Codes are as follows:

```
CABasicAnimation *rotateWhenBoom = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
rotateWhenBoom.fromValue = @0;
rotateWhenBoom.toValue = @(M_PI*2.0);
rotateWhenBoom.duration = 0.3f;
rotateWhenBoom.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];

CAAnimationGroup *boom = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
boom.animations = @[[self moveOutWithBtn:btn], rotateWhenBoom];
boom.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
boom.removedOnCompletion = NO;
```

And the effect:
[effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2gvB.png)

Before the animation the views are all horizontal. I add a rotation animation to these views, and the toValue of rotation is 2*PI. Why after the animation they are not horizontal?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Whats the issue? The posted effect is expected op or how it looks now! Are you saying that views goes back to their original position after animation? If thats the case use removedOnCompletion

Comment: I havent down voted your question

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Before the animation the views are all horizontal. I add a rotation animation to these views, and the toValue of rotation is 2*PI. Why after the animation they are not horizontal?

Comment: I checked your code its working fine buddy

Comment: @SandeepBhandari The rotation animation is in an animation group. Are they related? I really don't understand why they are not horizontal... Sorry!

Comment: Put the code for animation group as well

Answer (score 0):

Your last two lines of code:

`boom.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
boom.removedOnCompletion = NO;`

mean that the layer stays at the final state of animation and that the animation is not automatically removed from the layer when it completes. You probably want to remove the last line `boom.removeOnCompletion = NO`

A good guide for CALayer and CAAnimation that explains this: https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/animations-explained/